# Extract video code from a YouTube URL in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have Youtube video links in MS Excel and I want to extract the Youtube video code from the URL.

> URL:  https://youtu.be/2yTAyVXzFGg
>
> I need: 2yTAyVXzFGg

I tried using many combination with RIGHT() function but I didn't get the exact result.

> 1. =RIGHT(A2,SEARCH("/",A2)) this gives "yVXzFGg" as result.
> 2. =RIGHT(A2, LEN(A2)- SEARCH("/",A2) - LEN("/") + 1) this is showing "/youtu.be/2yTAyVXzFGg"

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use text to column with delimiter / under data tab.

[image]

If you want with formula then

> =RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("/",A2,9))

Comment: Yes this works but the problem is that it will give all the parts "https:. youtu.be, 2yTAyVXzFGg. I have other details about the link in next columns. Which I don't want disturb that's why I wanted the formula. I was using it earlier but I missed it and now I can't find it.

Comment: This formula is working. Just for my knowledge can you tell me the use 9 at the end of the formula?

Comment: 9 is the starting position from which SEARCH starts to search desired substring. your formula was searching from position 1 and was returning the position of 1st /

Comment: @Mohit it tells excel to start finding "/" from 9th character in your string.This is to avoid the first two "//"